# Custom IP header for ICMP packet not working

Tags: c, sockets, networking, ip, raw-sockets

I'm trying to make an ICMP packet with a custom IP header.
When I disable `IP_HDRINCL` to use the default IP header and cut out all the IP header related code, it works (I checked the checksums of the code below and the code that works with default headers, the ICMP packet is definitely valid in the code below).

The issue arrives when trying to use my own IP header, I don't receive any ICMP packets, indicating the packet didn't properly transmit or something went wrong.

I'm on Ubuntu 16.04 and compiling with GCC with the flags `-std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic`

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netinet/ip.h>
#include <netinet/udp.h>
#include <netinet/ip_icmp.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

#define PACKETSIZE 256

// Packet struct
struct packet {
    struct iphdr ip; // IP Header
    struct icmphdr hdr; // ICMP Header
    char msg[PACKETSIZE - sizeof(struct icmphdr) - sizeof(struct iphdr)]; // Message
};

// Checksum function
unsigned short checksum(void *b, int len) { 
    unsigned short *buf = b;
    unsigned int sum = 0;
    unsigned short result;

    for (sum = 0; len > 1; len -= 2) {
        sum += *buf++;
    }
    if (len == 1) sum += *(unsigned char*)buf;

    sum = (sum >> 16) + (sum & 0xFFFF);
    sum += (sum >> 16);
    result = ~sum;

    return result;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{   
    // Enough arguments
    if (argc < 2) {
        printf("usage: ./tracert <server>\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    // Variables
    struct hostent *hname;
    struct sockaddr_in addr;
    unsigned int i;
    int sockfd, seq = 1;
    struct packet pckt;
    socklen_t len;
    char buf[1024];

    // Get host from domain
    hname = gethostbyname(argv[1]);
    memset(&addr, 0, sizeof(addr));
    addr.sin_family = hname->h_addrtype;
    addr.sin_port = htons(6969);
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = *(long *)hname->h_addr_list[0]; 

    // Create ICMP RAW socket
    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_ICMP);
    if (sockfd < 0) {
        printf("error on socket creation\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;;
    }

    if (setsockopt(sockfd, IPPROTO_IP, IP_HDRINCL, &seq, sizeof(seq)) < 0) {
        printf("error on default ip header settings\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    // Loop and receive/send packets
    while (1) {
    // Make packet
        memset(&pckt, 0, sizeof(pckt));

        // IP Header
        pckt.ip.version = 4;
        pckt.ip.ihl = 5;
        pckt.ip.tot_len = htons(sizeof(pckt));
        pckt.ip.ttl = 255;
        pckt.ip.protocol = IPPROTO_ICMP;
        pckt.ip.saddr = inet_addr("192.168.1.1");
        pckt.ip.daddr = addr.sin_addr.s_addr;
        pckt.ip.check = checksum(&pckt, sizeof(struct iphdr));

        // ICMP Header
        pckt.hdr.type = ICMP_ECHO;
        pckt.hdr.un.echo.id = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < sizeof(pckt.msg) - 1; i++) {
            pckt.msg[i] = i+'0';
        }
        pckt.msg[i] = 0;
        pckt.hdr.un.echo.sequence = seq;
        pckt.hdr.checksum = checksum(&pckt.hdr, sizeof(struct icmphdr) + sizeof(pckt.msg));

        // Send packet
        if (sendto(sockfd, &pckt, sizeof(pckt), 0, (struct sockaddr*)&addr, sizeof(addr)) <= 0) {
            printf("error on sending packet\n");
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }

        // Receive packet
        len = sizeof(addr);
        memset(buf, 0, sizeof(buf));

        if (recvfrom(sockfd, buf, sizeof(buf), 0, (struct sockaddr*)&addr, &len) > 0) {
            printf("packet received\n");
            // Do more stuff here later...
        }

        // The while is there for later, for now I just want to send one packet
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }

    close(sockfd);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: I suggest you capture the packets with [wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/), and see how it decodes your IP header - being familiar with Wireshark will greatly help you find any issues with crafting your packets. You can also have Wireshark validate your checksums, to verify you got them correct. You are dividing pckt.ip.tot_len  by 8, which seems odd though there shouldn't be any reason for doing that. However you propably need to convert that value to network byte order (big endian)

Comment: @nos you are correct, I confused bits and bytes again. Edited the post. Wireshark is a good idea, I'll look into it

Comment: I just looked and apparently it doesn't take my IP header correctly. The total length is off, TTL is off, stuff like that, no idea why though, the protocol is correct.

Comment: I checked your program with `localhost` argument. Wireshark is able to capture the packet, and all the headers are valid, IP checksum is OK, ICMP checksum is OK. I even tried to change TTL to some different value - the change is visible in new packets. My kernel is `4.9.0-3-amd64`.

Comment: Hmm really weird, maybe it had something to do with my computer. Anyway I used another way, I used 2 sockets, on ICMP and an UDP one instead of the original attempted solution.